# Querying over #Entity dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, hashtag, wikidata, wikidata-api

**3 types of resource ways** that **dbpedia** provides. Just like given below.

```
1) http://dbpedia.org/page/Akshay_Kumar
2) http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q95
3) #Paris
```

1) It uses **RDF schema**. `<Subject Predicate Object>` technique. Using **SPARQL** query

```
    select str(?text) as ?text
    {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Akshay_Kumar> dbo:abstract  ?text 
    FILTER (lang(?text) = 'en')
    }
```

Above **SPARQL** query fetch the result from **dbpedia resource link**. I **attached** the **resource link** in given **below image**.
[image]

2) It use **Wikidata API**. It gives output in **JSON**. Using [Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q95&languages=en)

I **highlight** the **output** in below **image**.
[image]

3) So, I want **description property/ type** of **`#Paris`** entity. I *don't know* how to deal with **Fragment identifiers like #Paris**. Am I need sparql query or any API ? No Idea.

**BACKGROUND:**

I extracted all DBpedia superclass/subclass pairs, with this query --

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ?superclass 
                   ?subclass 
    WHERE  { ?subclass                a  owl:Class
                    ;  rdfs:subClassOf  ?superclass 
          } 
ORDER BY  ?superclass 
          ?subclass
```

Then I ran some other queries to get all instances (entities) of those classes.

```
... queries to come ...
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem, sorry. For 3) what is the input, what the expected output and the whole procedure should be based on which knowledge base?

Comment: @AKSW I want to extract the "abstract" property of #ENITIY (Ex. #Paris). I want same thing as I am doing 1). Hope you understand, what I am trying to say. If not. Please ping me back.

Comment: (1) How did you "extract all entity"? From where? (2) Fragment identifiers like `#Paris` are only useful when they accompany the URI of the resource in which they identify a fragment. On their own, fragment identifiers are little more use than literals. `#Paris` is not an entity identifier.

Comment: @TallTed First, I extracted classes and going one by one over each class and extract entities of them. I don't have too much knowledge about dbpedia. So, how to fetch the dbo:abstract property of Fragment identifiers like #Paris. and also how to accompany it with URI resource. Please help

Comment: @iNikkz - We need explicit "I ran this query against this interface/website" kind of information. I don't know what you mean by "extracted" here, neither for classes nor for entities (usually meaning instances) thereof.  You should probably edit your question to add this information -- as comments don't allow for enough content nor formatting -- and then comment to let us know you've edited.

Comment: @TallTed - I have edited my question. Please check. Attached some images/ output by which you can understand the question easily. Help me out. Thanks.

Comment: I still don't know where or how you got `#Paris`. I ask again -- *how* and *where* and *with what tool/query* did you *"extract"* the DBpedia entities?

Comment: @TallTed - I queried this - """ select Distinct ?superclass ?subclass where {
     ?subclass a owl:Class .
     ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf ?superclass
    } ORDER BY ?superclass ?subclass """ to get all classes.

Comment: @iNikkz - OK, that got you the classes. How did you then get the entities? if you used multiple queries, I'm particularly interested in the one that brought you `#Paris`.

Comment: @TallTed - Sorry, what you get after "#" is name of class not the entity. #Paris is just an example. The query I just posted above fetches classes like this (For Ex. - #TimeInterval, #UnitOfLength etc. having #<class_name>).

Comment: Where and how did you run this query, that you got such results? I have been unable to reproduce this against the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint. Further -- all the examples in your question were entities, not classes. Perhaps you should [tell us what you're trying to achieve, instead of focusing on this step in your planned path, so we can possibly put you on a better path](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for [programming questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is not a programming question.  To learn more about DBpedia, look to the[DBpedia website](http://dbpedia.org/), and the[DBpedia discussion mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion).